# How to allow \b in regex for sed command replace

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text file *temp.txt* containing

```
Hello World
My name is MayukhSarkar
My name is mayukh
My name is MAYUKH
My name is MaYuKh
My name is mAyUkH
```

The sed command

```
sed 's/\b[M,m][A,a][Y,y][U,u][K,k][H,h]\b/sobo/g' temp.txt
```

is not replacing the occurrences of `Mayukh` with `sobo`

but the sed command without `\b` is working

```
sed 's/[M,m][A,a][Y,y][U,u][K,k][H,h]/sobo/g' temp.txt
```

but it is also replacing the `MayukhSarkar` into `soboSarkar`

Comment: You don't use commas in `[]` classes. So `[M,m]` is the three characters `M`, `m`, and `,`. You want `[Mm]` instead.

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: Try to enclose the pattern into `\<` and `\>`.

Comment: I tried with [Mm] but it didn't work...Moreover sed -V other versions of it spit error

Comment: What do mean by enclose it with \< and \>

Comment: sed --version also spits error too

Comment: installing gnu sed will solve your issue then

Comment: `\<` and `\>` are word-boundary escapes that are specific to the left and right edges of a word (where `\b` is both). The suggestion was to try using `\<....\>` instead of `\b....\b`.

Comment: \< ... \> did not work..sorry..

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|[^[:alnum:]])[Mm][Aa][Yy][Uu][Kk][Hh]([^[:alnum:]]|$)/\1sobo\2/' file
Hello World
My name is MayukhSarkar
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
```

or with the Bedrock sed you seem to be using:

```
sed 's/\(^\|[^[:alnum:]]\)[Mm][Aa][Yy][Uu][Kk][Hh]\([^[:alnum:]]\|$\)/\1sobo\2/'
 file
```

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed 's/\bmayukh\b/sobo/i' file                   
Hello World
My name is MayukhSarkar
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
```

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {sub(/\<mayukh\>/,"sobo")} 1' file                
Hello World
My name is MayukhSarkar
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'match(tolower($0),/(^|[[:space:]])mayukh([[:space:]]|$)/) { tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"sobo",tgt); $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file
Hello World
My name is MayukhSarkar
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
My name is sobo
```

Comment: If I remove the -r then \1 is not defined in RE

Comment: NOTE: for `OS X` and some versions of `sed` the `regex` option is `-E` and not `-r`.

Comment: it's time for awk inserting in gameplay

Comment: I added a version that doesn't require -r or -E so it's portable.

Comment: Moreover can you please tell how to check the sed version in OSX & install gnu sed in OS X

Comment: No, I can't, I don't use that platform. That would certainly be a new question to a very different audience!

Comment: Ed it seems that your second version still uses the ERE `|` operator so I don't think it's actually portable.

Comment: @bkmoney I just mean portable in that it doesn't rely on a specific argument, `-r`, or `-E` to enable EREs since that seems to be the main differentiator between modern seds - not can they handle EREs or not but what arg do you use to tell them to recognize unescaped ERE metachars.

Comment: yeah most RE engines can tackle that

Comment: @josifoski If you can come up with an awk solution that would be great. I'm having trouble since awk doesn't really support captured groups.

Comment: @bkmoney OP could save time all of us if instead \b uses simple space. For awk there are profs here (noticed that you also gave several good solutions) -> to django or not to django Shaekspere gpl

Comment: @bkmoney GNU awk has gensub() and match(str,re,**arr**) which both do support capture groups. In general with any non-gawk you need to use match()+substr() to simulate capture groups. I added a couple of awk solutions to demonstrate.

Comment: @EdMorton Wow without GNU awk it seems really tedious to get the captured groups to work

Comment: @bkmoney yeah and it's a poor mans substitute - consider how you'd do it globally on each line instead of once (hint it's a non-trivial loop)! That's what drives gawk extensions - the difficulty of doing the job otherwise. There's lots of enhancements that COULD be introduced to gawk fairly easily but then you end up with language bloat (e.g. p*** :-) ) so the gawk guys focus on just providing enhancements for functionality that's extremely difficult to write otherwise. The world just needs to get GNU awk :-).

Comment: I would recommend using `gsub` with `awk`, particularly if this is meant to work across different versions. The last solution should work on almost any, although it's simply too long in my opinion.

Comment: You would be wrong in that recommendation. You can't do this task robustly with `gsub()` (except in GNU awk as I showed but then GNU sed is even more concise) and if the OP is happy with a script that messes with white space and relies on only white space around words, there is a simpler and more robust awk solution.

Comment: `awk` is really not the best choice to go with on this anyway; what's essentially `wrong` starts there. Also `gsub` is perfectly capable of dealing with whitespace, and which simpler `awk` solution are you referring?

Comment: Try to make your solution NOT add white space for the given example and you;ll see one of the gsub() limitations. Now try it if the text just can't be surrounded by any non-word characters to see more. The simplest approach if all words are space-separated and the OP doesn't care about preserving white space is a loop on fields.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` should work the best:

```
sed -E 's/(^| )[Mm][Aa][Yy][Uu][Kk][Hh]( |[^S]|$)/\1sobo\2/g' temp.txt
```

In `OS X` the `-E` option will interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions (ERE's) rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's). In `Linux` this would be `-r`.

Using `awk` with `gsub` it's fairly simple to replace specific case-insensitive words:

```
awk '{gsub(/(^| )[Mm][Aa][Yy][Uu][Kk][Hh]( |$)/," sobo ");print}' temp.txt
```

This should work across all platforms, `OS X`, `Linux`, etc.

EDIT: If the words to be replaced happens to be either at the beginning or end or the line then you would need to complicate the pattern a bit:

```
awk '{gsub(/(^| )[Mm][Aa][Yy][Uu][Kk][Hh]( |$)/,"-sobo-");gsub(/^-sobo-/,"sobo ");gsub (/-sobo-$/," sobo");gsub (/-sobo-/," sobo "); print}'
```

This will essentially make it so that there is not a space in front or in back of the replaced word.

**Results:**

```
My name is MayukhSarkar
My name is sobo 
My name is sobo 
My name is sobo 
My name is sobo
```

Comment: It's not the easy - what you posted adds a space to the beginning or end of the line if/when `mayukh` occurrs in that position.

Comment: The second awk command above would corrupt the file if `-sobo-` existed in the file before the command was run.

Comment: @EdMorton, Now you're just being nit picky. My advice is to use `sed` anyway, and I'm tempted to remove the `awk` example altogether, as it's not adding anything of value to the answer.

Comment: nit picky? Not at all, even on my laziest lazy day I'd never consider adding a plain-text string and then having to remove it hoping that it didn't already exist in the input! If you want to use this approach then the right way is `awk '{gsub(/a/,"aA");gsub(/(^| )[Mm][Aa][Yy][Uu][Kk][Hh]( |$)/,"aB");gsub(/^aB/,"sobo ");gsub (/aB$/," sobo");gsub (/aB/," sobo "); gsub(/aA/,"a"); print}'` but that would still fail for the case of mayukh on a line of it's own.